# If $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ are three mutually perpendicular non coplanar unit vectors then...

Tags: vectors

***Prove that $[\vec{a}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{a}+[\vec{b}\vec{p}\vec{q}]\vec{b}+[\vec{c}\vec{p}\vec{q}]\vec{c}={\vec{p}} × {\vec{q}}$***

Here $[\vec{d}\vec{e}\vec{f}]$ denotes scalar triple product.

My attempt at solving this:

$$Let \space \vec{p}=x\vec{a}+y\vec{b}+z\vec{c}$$
$$Let \space \vec{q}=m\vec{a}+n\vec{b}+o\vec{c}$$
$$\vec{p}\times \vec{q}=({\vec{a}} \times {\vec{b}})(xn-ym)+(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})(yo-zn)+(\vec{a}\times\vec{c})(xo-zm)$$
$$[\vec{a}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{a}=[\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{c}](yo-zn)\vec{a}$$
$$[\vec{b}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{b}=[\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{c}](xo-zm)\vec{b}$$
$$[\vec{c}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{c}=[\vec{a }\vec{b}\vec{c}](xn-ym)\vec{c}$$
$$[\vec{a}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{a}+[\vec{b}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{b}+[\vec{c}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{c}=?$$
I don't know how to proceed further, someone please help

Comment: $=\vec{p}x \vec{q}$ $\;-\;$ What is $\,x\,$?