# If $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ are three non coplanar mutually perpendicular unit vectors then...

Tags: vectors

***Prove that $[\vec{a}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{a}+[\vec{b}\vec{p}\vec{q}]\vec{b}+[\vec{c}\vec{p}\vec{q}]\vec{c}={\vec{p}} × {\vec{q}}$***

Here $[\vec{d}\vec{e}\vec{f}]$ denotes scalar triple product.

My attempt at solving this:

$$Let \space \vec{p}=x\vec{a}+y\vec{b}+z\vec{c}$$
$$Let \space \vec{q}=m\vec{a}+n\vec{b}+o\vec{c}$$
$$\vec{p}\times \vec{q}=({\vec{a}} \times {\vec{b}})(xn-ym)+(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})(yo-zn)+(\vec{a}\times\vec{c})(xo-zm)$$
$$[\vec{a}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{a}=[\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{c}](yo-zn)\vec{a}$$
$$[\vec{b}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{b}=[\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{c}](xo-zm)\vec{b}$$
$$[\vec{c}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{c}=[\vec{a }\vec{b}\vec{c}](xn-ym)\vec{c}$$
$$[\vec{a}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{a}+[\vec{b}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{b}+[\vec{c}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{c}=?$$
I don't know how to proceed further, someone please help

Comment: You should have edited the original question, rather than [deleting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217527/if-veca-vecb-vecc-are-three-non-coplanar-unit-vectors-then) and reposting. Anyway, what do you mean by $[a\vec{p} \vec{q}]a$, specifically what is the significance of the square brackets and of the missing vector signs?

Comment: @dxiv it was a typo, and [ ] denotes scalar triple product

Comment: Did you miss something?  The dimensions don't agree on both sides.

Comment: @NgChungTak I can't understand what you mean, can you explain it once more

Comment: LHS is order $4$ while RHS is order $2$.

Comment: Compare with Cramer's rule of $3$ variables:
$$[abc]d=[dbc]a+[adc]b+[abd]c$$

Comment: @Sunaina So you want to prove $(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{u}) \vec{a} + (\vec{b} \cdot \vec{u}) \vec{b}  + (\vec{c} \cdot \vec{u}) \vec{c} = \vec{u}$ where $u = \vec{p} \times \vec{q}$. Problem is that the equality does not hold true with (just) the given assumptions.

Comment: @dxiv yes that's what I want to prove

Comment: @NgChungTak, in that case it gets simplified again to [apq]a since the scalar triple product of is zero if two vectors are the same

Comment: @dxiv you're correct there is an error in the question, the vectors are mutually perpendicular

Comment: @Sunaina In that case let $\vec u = x \vec a + y \vec b + z \vec c\,$, then show that $x = \vec a \cdot \vec u\,$, $y = \dots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: @dxiv gave me an important hint

$$\text{ Assume } \space \vec{p} \times \vec{q}=\vec{u} $$
$$\vec{u}=d\vec{a}+e\vec{b}+f\vec{c}$$
$$(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{u})\vec{a}=d\vec{a} $$
$$(\vec{b} \cdot \vec{u})\vec{b}=e\vec{a} $$
$$(\vec{c} \cdot \vec{u})\vec{c}=f\vec{a} $$
Thus $$[\vec{a}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{a}+[\vec{b}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{b}+[\vec{c}\vec{p} \vec{q}]\vec{c}= \vec{p} \times \vec{q}$$